# Mean number of individuals/ha per species in R

Tags: r, aggregate

I have a dataset much like that:

```
dat<-data.frame(Plot_ID=c("P_1","P_1","P_2","P_3","P_3"),
                Name=c("Spec1","Spec2","Spec3","Spec1","Spec4"),
                Number=c(2,3,1,5,2))
```

The Plot_ID is the plot where the species were acessed, the Name is the name of the species and the Number is the amount found in that plot. I want to find out per species the amountof individuals overall.

My problem is, that of course not each species is represented in each plot. In this case the mean number of individuals of Spec2 would be 3/3 per plot. If i use the aggregate function like so:

```
agg.1<-aggregate(dat$Number, list(dat$Name),mean)
```

The number of individuals for Spec2 is 3, which is not what i wanted. And I don't really want to add each species into each plot with a 0 value, where it doesn't appear.

EDID To clarify my desired result

My desired result would be something like that:

```
Name N/plot
Spec1 2.3 #Amount of individuals=7/Amount of plots=3
Spec2 1   #3/3
Spec3 0.3 #1/3
Spec4 0.6 #2/3
```

Comment: The result for Spec4 should be 2/5 = 0.4?

Comment: Actually 2/3=0.66, the mean per plot is important. Sorry I made a mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dplyr...

```
library(dplyr)

# output to dataframe newdf
newdf <- dat %>%
  group_by() %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Name, n) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Number)) %>% 
  mutate(agg.1 = total / n)
```

Result:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   Name [4]
    Name     n total agg.1
  <fctr> <int> <dbl> <dbl>
1  Spec1     5     7   1.4
2  Spec2     5     3   0.6
3  Spec3     5     1   0.2
4  Spec4     5     2   0.4
```

If you want the results in a vector, you can use the `pull` function (dplyr >= 0.7):

```
agg1. <- dat %>%
  group_by() %>% 
  mutate(n = n()) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(Name, n) %>%
  summarise(total = sum(Number)) %>% 
  mutate(agg.1 = total / n) %>%
  pull(agg.1)
```

Comment: Thanks! I think this is the right direction, however it shows me the mean amount of individuals per plot, for each plot separately. But i i searching for the overall mean (I specified my desired result in my question)

Comment: Updated code, all rows match except the last one - can you provide more detail if this isn't correct please?

Comment: I see now, I did this in a rush. I'm sorry for that. The amount I want to didvide it with is the amount of levels "Plot_ID" has, so actually 3 in this case. But I think I can wok with that, what you have gien me. How do I export the entire result as a data.frame?

Comment: Updated to show how to output to dataframe. Please accept answer if you are happy with it.